# What is going on with kerning when comparing math italics to italics?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, italic, kerning

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Math    & $AUC$ \\
        Italics & \textit{AUC} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In math mode the C is too far away from the U and in italics the space seems to be the same between A and U. Is there a reason for these strange kernings and are these set in stone and will never be changed or can one expect them to be improved sometime in the future?

Comment: The metrics for computer modern will not change ever.  TeX doesn't have to use computer modern though.

Comment: Ah so this is a case of whatever bug is still there will now be considered a feature or however it was put?

Comment: this is not a bug.  the metrics of the `cmmi` font are designed for proper placement of sub- and superscripts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
$AUC$
\textit{AUC}
\end{document}
```

produces in the `.log` some detail about the typesetting of the elements:

```
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 A
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 U
....\kern1.09026
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 C
....\kern0.71527
....\mathoff
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 A
....\kern-0.25557
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 U
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 C
....\kern 1.45276
....\penalty 10000
```

Note how the construction of `AUC` in the first `\mathon`...`\mathoff` section comes from a different *font* `cmm` and that `\kern`s (spaces) are inserted after `U` and `C`. In comparison, a `\kern` is inserted after `A` and `C` in the second non-math component (also set in a different font `cmr`).

Here the take on the setting of the elements are that in math mode, adjacent elements are typically considered variables that are multiplied, while in text mode they represent something completely different. Perhaps a better example that exacerbates the spacing differences comes from using letters that form ligatures in text mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
$off$
\textit{off}
\end{document}
```

`\showoutput` highlights this:

```
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 o
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764
....\mathoff
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10  (ligature ff)
....\kern 2.11945
....\penalty 10000
```

Answer (score 5):

The letters used in `$AUC$` are from the `cmmi` family. They are slightly wider than than the same letters in `cmti` (text italic), but they have slightly smaller sidebearings. In math mode an italic correction is added after each letter. For `A` this is zero, and the one after `C` is not apparent unless something follows it or one uses `\showoutput` to exhibit it. The italic correction is the sole means of avoiding collisions between charaters in math. You would absolutely need this correction after `U` in something like `$|U|$`, but TeX doesn't check if the next symbol is slanted or upright, it just always adds the correction.

The math alphabet font `cmmi`, like most math fonts, has almost no kern or ligature information. Text fonts like `cmti` have a lot of such information and it is used to insert a positive kern beween `A` and `U`. You can get text italic to look a lot like math italic if you manually insert italic corrections: `\textit{A\/U\/C\/}`.

In text, it is expected that letters that immediately follow one another belong to the same word and the kerning information is intended to make them blend harmoniously. In math, there is typically no connection between adjacent letters and it would be misleading to try to make it look that way. If a sequence of letters in math is used to make up a single variable then one uses `\mathit{AUC}`, which just uses the same font as `\textit{AUC}` and uses all the kerning information in that font.

So the large space between `U` and `C` in math and the small one between `A` and `U` are not really intentional, but rather just not considered important enough to justify a more elaborate system.

Answer (score 4):

Your first AUC in math mode means `A multiplied by U multiplied by C`. Hence not only there is no kerning as in the words, but also all spaces (you have not got them here, but you can try) are ignored. It is not a bug, it is a feature, so the user should remember of proper inserting (via `\mathit` or `\textit`) words in math mode.

Comment: But there is no difference between the multiplication of A with U  and the multiplication of U with C so it can hardly be considered a feature that the spacing between them differs this much...